# This question already exists

Tags: support, questions, moderation, close-reasons, closed-questions

[Read this first.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/176387/why-the-boolean-modifier-behaves-weirdly?noredirect=1#comment295798_176387)

So I came to this point where I had enough and came to figure things out here. I've been using this site for almost a month, but recently I started getting pressure from this one mod. Today is the day, when my post got deleted for the second time, not the same question, but a different one. Apparently, it is a "duplicate" question. The post was hidden and I was provided with those duplicate questions, one was already researched before and it didn't work, the other one was obsolete so it didn't work too.

I always try to figure things on my own before I ask my teacher, just like here. But when you can't, you just ask. But things here seem different, though not sure yet. I posted a new question, providing even more details, like the protruding ring lines in the picture, which wasn't shown the first time. It's hidden again, because duplication. Well, how do you ask otherwise when those other peoples' problems are similar, but I have different outcomes and their provided solutions doesn't solve mine?

[image]

This is what should be at least fixed, if the moderator is proved to be not guilty. **"If this question doesn't resolve your question, ask a new one."** OK, the text obviously means that if the provided questions by the moderator doesn't resolve my problem, I should ask a new one again (at least, that's how most people understand). And like I said before, I did ask a new one, it got hidden, then I edited it, evaluating the mod's work. If it's a duplicate, then provide how is it the same, give proof not just "I pressed a couple of buttons, read this question and figure it yourself." I have never experienced this kind of situation, although I ask a lot when there's no other way, that's called activity, but here it's seems the opposite of it.

Comment: Again, as I stated in my first comment in your duplicate question and I quote: "*If you feel your question was incorrectly closed as duplicate please **edit it**, providing additional information on the steps you took and why they didn't solve your problem so it can be reopened.*" Editing it will bump it up the question queue making it more visible again, will notify users it was edited after being closed, and will place it in a review queue so we can take a look at it.

Comment: Also take a look at https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates especially the last lines. Getting questions closed for being duplicates is quite common and there is nothing wrong with it except for frequent offenders or blatant duplicates. What is at fault here is your disproportionate reaction and generally offensive attitude towards others. If you keep that up other measures will be taken

Comment: nope, it says "Your post has been associated with similar questions. If these questions don’t resolve your question, ask a new one."

Comment: you're failing dude, just admit it.

Comment: @Duarte My only duplicate on a sibling site doesn't show that message. Would it be possible to contact someone to fix it? Asking a wrongly-duped question again does not make any sense to me.

Comment: @Leander I've added some related links in my [answer](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2718/241).

Comment: Thanks Ray. So the question that remains is why is the OP seeing the notice encouraging to ask a new question rather than the one asking to edit it?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos The answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337015/311571) shows `status-declined` and Shog9's comment below it explains why. So maybe as you closed it without letting it go to a general vote (I don't know if you can do a 'regular' vote as a moderator) it didn't trigger the 'edit' suggestion.

Comment: "*I don't know if you can do a 'regular' vote as a moderator*" You can't unfortunately, mod votes are always binding, hence why I sometimes refrain from close voting questions. It may also be that since the duplicate is just the identical question from the same user and has no answers (accepted or otherwise), the message differs from normal.

Answer (score 2):

I understand you want to get this sorted and you're probably frustrated with this process.

1. The message you are seeing on your question is slightly misleading and I understand why you asked the question again.
2. A closed question is not hidden from anyone and it can be voted to be reopened by users who have enough reputation (not just moderators).
3. Drop the petty comments. They just wont get you anywhere and will make people less likely to want to help you. No one is 'guilty' or 'failing'.

I don't know if the message you're seeing on your question suggesting you ask the question again has always been like that or whether it's changed recently, but it does seem misleading. What Duarte is suggesting is *correct* and what we advise *anyone* to do when a question has been closed and they feel it shouldn't have been: *edit it* and explain why the answers in the duplicate don't help or why your question is different. Once edited your question will enter the review queue and if the edits clearly (*and calmly*) explain why the duplicate question isn't a duplicate, people will vote for it to be reopened.

**To summarise**:

- I understand the message you're seeing is different from what Duarte suggested, but he is *correct*. And he has, in my opinion, dealt with this correctly, despite your comments towards him.
- To proceed, use the 'edit' link below the question you want reopened to add information explaining how it's not a duplicate or how the answers don't help.
- Threats or rudeness aimed at *any* user will not be tolerated.

This post goes over this quite thoroughly:

[Someone flagged my question as already answered, but it's not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not)

**Some other related posts** (slightly unclear which posts relate to how the site *currently* works):

- ["Please ask a new question" encourages question repetition for duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174744/please-ask-a-new-question-encourages-question-repetition-for-duplicates)
- [Duplicate explanation should encourage improvement of original](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166525/duplicate-explanation-should-encourage-improvement-of-original)
- [How could we improve our planned post notice improvements?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332500/311571)
- [New Post Notices rollout on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337015/311571)

Comment: slightly misleading..? This "slightly" misleading is the main reason it causes confusion, I don't know if the mods can write those private feedbacks or they are automated messages, but damn, fix it or something. It's like if I was working a sorter job where the rule is to sort plastic bottles to the plastic bin only, but then I get a message from my boss saying, that there's going to be an accidental glass bottle coming up on the conveyor belt and gave me an order to throw that into plastic bin. You'd be confused, whether you should follow the rules or listen to boss. Same happens here.